# Quarkus: Cannot @Inject MongoClient using Kotlin

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, cdi, inject, quarkus

I created a simple Kotlin Quarkus application that connects to my local MongoDB instance following [the official guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb).

The connection works, however it seems that it fails to inject the MongoClient/ReactiveMongoClient like so:

```
...
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient
...

@ApplicationScoped
open class KotlinService @Inject constructor(private val mongoClient: MongoClient) {

    fun getCollection(): MongoCollection<Document> = mongoClient.getDatabase("test").getCollection("hello")

}
```

Calling `getCollection()` results in:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:106)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:372)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:496)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:252)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:153)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:363)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:156)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:238)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:118)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.lambda$handle$0(VertxRequestHandler.java:74)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$2(ContextImpl.java:316)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at ...service.KotlinService.getCollection(KotlinService.kt:12)
        at ...resource.ReceiptResource.getAll(ReceiptResource.kt:19)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        .....
```

If I rewrite the class in Java instead it works fine:

```
...
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
...

@ApplicationScoped
public class JavaService {

    private MongoClient mongoClient;

    @Inject
    public JavaService(MongoClient mongoClient) {
        this.mongoClient = mongoClient;
    }

    public MongoCollection<Document> getCollection() {
        return mongoClient.getDatabase("test").getCollection("hello");
    }
}
```

A bug or am I missing something here?

**Update**

Reported as a bug on [github](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6264).

Comment: This looks like a bug. Can you please open an issue and ping me on it (`geoand` on github as well)?

Comment: Is it working if you inject into the `mongoClient` field instead of a constructor ?

Comment: Nope still null :/

Comment: Added a comment: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6264#issuecomment-568251711